# GCC 7 C++ 17 support for folding expressions

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, gcc7

The following snippet will compile in GCC 8+, but fails to compile in GCC 7.

```
template <typename... THINGS>
struct A
{
  explicit A(THINGS *... things)
  {
    (..., [thing = things](){}());
  }
};


int main()
{
    int thing;
    const auto thingy = A{&thing};
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/D3URBW)

The stated failure is that the parameter pack isn't being expanded: `parameter packs not expanded with '...'`.
Checking the [GCC standards compliance page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), fold expressions should be supported in GCC 7.

Is there another flag i need besides `std=c++17`? (i didn't see one)
Is the standard not yet completely implemented? (i didn't see anything indicating that)
Can i make this work, or is this just a GCC 7 bug i'm going to have to work around?

Comment: FWIW you should be able to use the array trick: `int discard[] = {([thing = things](){}(), 0)...};`

Comment: @NathanOliver But this gives the same error, because of the same GCC bug?

Comment: @uneven_mark Oh.  I thought the issue was the fold expression itself, not that the lambda capture was breaking the expression.  Now that I've actually read the bug I see that it will indeed not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85305), originally reported in version 8.01, fixed in version 8.2. It seems that the bug also occurs when fold-expressions are not used (the C++11-era "expander trick" mentioned by NathanOliver doesn't work either), so you'll have to use a longer workaround that doesn't require expanding a template parameter pack that is inside a lambda capture. For example:

```
template <typename THING>
void do_it(THING* thing) {
    [thing]{}();
}

explicit A(THINGS *... things)
{
    (..., do_it(things));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a GCC bug. Found the [tracked](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85305) issue, fixed in 8.2.